# Bounds of integration for the marginals of a p.d.f

Tags: probability

If I have a probability density function $f(x,y)=2$ where $x>0, y>0, x+y<1$ is it correct to say that the marginals  $f_X(x)=\int_0^{1-x}2dy = 2(1-x)$ and that
$f_Y(y)=\int_0^{1-y}2dx = 2(1-y)$. What I am most confused about is the bounds of integration. Any tips or insights much appreciated.

Comment: You are right! Study Fubini's theorem for more insight in this kind of excercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to see if you write the "where" - condition as charistic function of that set, so:

$$f(x,y) = 2\cdot 1_{\{x>0\}}\cdot 1_{\{y>0\}} \cdot 1_{\{x+y<1\}}$$

Then you use definition of the marginal:

$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\cdot 1_{\{x>0\}}\cdot 1_{\{y>0\}} \cdot 1_{\{x+y<1\}} dy$$

And then it's easy to see that you have to consider the characteristic functions which affect $y$, so $y>0$ and $y < 1-x$ and so you can adapt the limits to:

$$f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{1-x} 2\cdot 1_{\{x>0\}} dy$$

So to be correct it leads to: $$f_X(x) = 1_{\{x>0\}}\int_{0}^{1-x} 2 dy$$

So ofc $f_X$ equals zero for $x \le 0$